# XSL key to get elements that meet specific criteria

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working with table entry elements and want to get all preceding entry elements in the same table that pass the following test:

```
parent::row/preceding-sibling::row/entry
  [@morerows >= count(parent::row/following-sibling::row
    [not(preceding-sibling::row/entry
      [generate-id() = $id])])]
  [count(preceding-sibling::entry
    [not(@morerows)]) + 1 = count(current()/preceding-sibling::entry) + 1]
```

The XPath gives me the desired result, but it is painfully slow.....  I would like to use a key but am having problems.

I defined  a key as follows:

```
<xsl:key name="moreRowsEntry" match="entry[@morerows]" use="."/>
```

While the key does retrieve all entry elements with the morerows attribute, I actually only need it to retrieve those within the same ancestor table. As well, I am at a loss as to how to test the morerows value.  I have tried things such as :

`<xsl:for-each select="key('moreRowsEntry', (@morerows >= count(parent::row/following-sibling::row[not(preceding-sibling::row/entry[generate-id() = $id])])) and (count(preceding-sibling::entry[not(@morerows)]) + 1 = count(current()/preceding-sibling::entry) + 1))">`

I have to do this using XSL 1.0. Any and all help is appreciated.

Some further information:

I am converting a CALS table to OOXML. For each entry in the CALS table that is within a row in which I know there are cells missing, I need to add those additional cells. For these entry elements I have an `$id` that is the generate-id() value of the element.

I then have the XPath from above, which tests that any entry elements in the preceding rows of the table (`parent::row/preceding-sibling::row/entry`) that have a morerows attribute that is greater than or equal to the number of rows between itself and the entry with the id of `$id`, and that are in the correct position in which the empty cell should be inserted (`count(preceding-sibling::entry[not(@morerows)]) + 1 = count(current()/preceding-sibling::entry) + 1`)

Simplified Sample Input:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <row>
            <entry morerows="2">A</entry>
            <entry morerows="1">B</entry>
            <entry>C</entry>
            <entry>D</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>E</entry>
            <entry>F</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>G</entry>
            <entry>H</entry>
            <entry>I</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>J</entry>
            <entry>K</entry>
            <entry>L</entry>
            <entry>M</entry>
        </row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Simplified Sample Output:

```
<w:tbl>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>A</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>B</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>C</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>D</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>E</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>F</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>H</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>I</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>J</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>K</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>L</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>M</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

The input uses the morerows attribute to specify spanned rows. The output requires that actual cells be inserted with the `<w:vMerge/>` element for each spanned cell.

Another sample:

In this sample, there are also merged columns (specified by the namest and nameend attributes) that must also be taken in to account:

```
<table>
    <tgroup cols="7">
        <colspec colname="col1"/>
        <colspec colname="col2"/>
        <colspec colname="col3"/>
        <colspec colname="col4"/>
        <colspec colname="col5"/>
        <colspec colname="col6"/>
        <colspec colname="col7"/>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry morerows="5">A</entry>
                <entry morerows="1">B</entry>
                <entry morerows="1">C</entry>
                <entry>D</entry>
                <entry>E</entry>
                <entry>F</entry>
                <entry>G</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>2D</entry>
                <entry>2E</entry>
                <entry>2F</entry>
                <entry>2G</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry morerows="1">3B</entry>
                <entry morerows="1">3C</entry>
                <entry>3D</entry>
                <entry>3E</entry>
                <entry>3F</entry>
                <entry>3G</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>4D</entry>
                <entry>4E</entry>
                <entry>4F</entry>
                <entry>4G</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry morerows="1" nameend="col6" namest="col2">3G - 4G</entry>
                <entry morerows="1">5G</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

Output:

```
<w:tbl>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>A</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>B</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>C</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>D</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>E</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>F</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>2D</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>2E</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>2F</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>2G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3B</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3C</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3D</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3E</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3F</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>4D</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>4E</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>4F</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>4G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:gridSpan w:val="5"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>3G - 4G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>5G</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

Comment: That's a complicated condition. Can you explain it in English, or explain the motivation for it? That will help.

Comment: An example of sample input and output would also be helpful.

Comment: Ah... the `morerows` attribute indicates a vertical span, from docbook (http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/entry.html). rowspans are a bear. I'm impressed that you got it to work at all in XSLT 1.0. But again, an English explanation of the condition would be helpful (including an indication of which entry `$id` refers to).

Comment: Sorry Lars - should have been more clear. My head was swimming yesterday from this problem :)

Comment: So is `$id` equivalent to `generate-id(current())` in the context that the above XPath expression is evaluated in?

Comment: Yes, and in this case it is an entry element.

Comment: OK, I think I understand the problem now. A sample input/output would still be helpful.

Comment: I've added simplified input/output samples that will hopefully do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I've updated my answer (before seeing the sample input/output).

Comment: Arggh. I was thankful to see from your earlier example input that there were no colspans (merged columns... namest/nameend). Guess I should have asked. That makes it a lot harder.

Answer (score 2):

If your processor can do [the `exslt:node-set` function](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/index.html) or an equivalent such as [that provided by msxml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) then you could attack this procedurally, using a tail-recursive template.  Ugly, I know, and completely against what we usually recommend for XSLT, but in this case I think the only way to do this efficiently is to pass information from one row to the next.  Assuming that the *first* row of the table will always have an `entry` for every column, then how about something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tbody">
  <w:tbl>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="rowSpec">
        <!-- build the row info structure assuming that the first row has
             the right number of entry elements.  Nothing spans into the
             first row, so they all get @span=0 -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[1]/entry">
          <r span="0" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </w:tbl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:param name="rowSpec" />
  <xsl:variable name="theRow" select="." />

  <w:tr>
    <!-- build up the output for this row -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rowSpec)/r">
      <w:tc>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@span = 0">
            <!-- this row has an entry for the column -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$theRow/entry[
               count(current()/preceding-sibling::r[@span = 0]) + 1]" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- this column spans from the previous row -->
            <w:tcPr>
              <w:vMerge/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </w:tc>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </w:tr>

  <!-- process the next row with recalculated spans -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::row[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="rowSpec">
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rowSpec)/r">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@span = 0">
            <!-- we had an entry element for this column, use its @morerows
                 as the next span, or 0 if it doesn't have one -->
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$theRow/entry[
                 count(current()/preceding-sibling::r[@span = 0]) + 1]/@morerows">
                <r span="{$theRow/entry[
                 count(current()/preceding-sibling::r[@span = 0]) + 1]/@morerows}" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <r span="0" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- we didn't have an entry for this column, it was a span from the
                 previous row - subtract 1 from the span when we pass on to
                 the next row -->
            <r span="{@span - 1}" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <w:t><xsl:value-of select="." /></w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</xsl:template>
```

(Wow, that ended up much more complex than I expected when I started it, but I've tested it out and it seems to work correctly).  The idea here is that we build a structure that encodes the number of rows that each column still needs to span over at the point where that row is processed.  So for the first row we'll have

```
<r span="0"/>
<r span="0"/>
<r span="0"/>
<r span="0"/>
```

then for the second it'll be

```
<r span="2"/>
<r span="1"/>
<r span="0"/>
<r span="0"/>
```

the third

```
<r span="1"/>
<r span="0"/>
<r span="0"/>
<r span="0"/>
```

etc.  For each row we then iterate over *this structure* rather than over the `entry` elements themselves.

---

Edit: now you've changed the question so you need to account for the possibility of column spans as well as row spans it gets much much messier.  Since we're committed to using a node-set function, I would think about a two-step approach as hinted at by LarsH, where you first expand out the column spanning entries into real `entry` elements (with some attribute to identify them as such) and then process the expanded version of the XML in place of the original.

Comment: +1, a good approach. I was thinking how much easier this would be to do procedurally, but hadn't taken the next step toward implementing it by recursion.

Comment: +1 - Definitely interesting. I can't use the exsl:node-set function "out of the box", but may be able to get one of my developers to integrate for me. Unfortunately, summer vacation has taken most away for a few weeks!

Comment: @Jacqueline which processor are you using? If it's an msxml based one then that has its own node-set function in a different namespace.

Comment: @IanRoberts - we use msxml, so it is definitely feasible. And the more I look at this the more I like the concepts. A very interesting approach.

Comment: @IanRoberts - I've run into a problem when columns are spanned. The "missing" cells are inserted as empty. And because we processing the r we don't know if the related entry has a column span or not. Not sure where to add column spanning logic to your code. I will post another example.

Comment: I'm having to do this myself now, i.e. transform a table with rowspan/colspan into a table without that. I think I'll be using your algorithm, modified to include colspan info in the rowSpec that you pass along in your recursive template. I'll try to post something on this page if I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I would first use a key that matches entries by their ancestor table:

```
<xsl:key name="moreRowsEntriesByTable" match="entry[@morerows]"
   use="generate-id(ancestor::table[1])" />
```

Hopefully you can use that to narrow down the set of nodes that you have to process in XPath. But I confess I haven't really understood the condition you're trying to filter by, so I'm not positive that the above is applicable.

### Update

Re: "I can't figure out how to include my XPath condition and get a result." I often get frustrated in XSLT 1.0 at the awkwardness of trying to combine a key with a preceding:: or following:: axis. It can't be done succinctly.

You could work it in by inserting the following predicate where needed:

```
[count(key('moreRowsEntriesByTable', $table-id) | .) = 
 count(key('moreRowsEntriesByTable', $table-id)]
```

where $table-id is the id of the current() node's ancestor table:

```
<xsl:variable name="table-id" select="generate-id(ancestor::table[1])" />
```

But that may be slower than not using a key at all:

```
[generate-id(ancestor::table[1]) = $table-id]
```

You could attach this predicate to each `entry` node test in you XPath expression. But again, I'm not sure it would help with performance.

### Alternative

Instead, I would suggest a two-stage transformation. Does your processing context allow that? For that, you can either run two stylesheets, with the output of the first piped to the input of the second; or use the common `node-set()` extension function to convert the output of one template to a node set that can serve as input to another template.

In the first transformation, you could add attributes to each table cell to help with the computation, such as...

```
@row -- row number of this entry in current table (position() of parent::row)
@index -- position of this entry among siblings in the parent::row, taking into
  account their colspans if necessary.
@table-id -- generate-id(ancestor::table[1])
```

The idea would be amortization (if I'm applying that term correctly)...
If these values are computed once per entry, in the first stage, instead of many times, in the complicated XPath expression, that could make things quite a bit faster. Maybe there are other attributes that would be more helpful.

You could remove (not copy) these helper attributes in the second transformation.

This is a sketchy suggestion, but maybe it will help point toward a good solution.

Comment: I'm still not sure about what to include in the key function, which seems to be my main stumbling block. I can't figure out how to include my XPath condition and get a result.

Comment: @Jacqueline: I wonder if it's possible to build a composite key, where `key('mykey', concat(rownum, 'x', position-in-row)` yields the set of `<entry>` elements whose @morerows span the coordinate passed as a key. Just brainstorming.

Comment: I appreciate the brainstorming! I believe you are out of my league when it comes to keys though - I think I need it more spelled out.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really think of a way to make it work in 1.0 either. XPath 2.0 would make it a lot easier.