# Convert HTML colspan and rowspan to "empty" cells

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

For a certain output format (*not* HTML-like), I need to convert HTML tables to 'square' tables, where each `colspan` and `rowspan` is not only indicated in the parent cell, but also followed by the correct number of empty cells.

For example, the simple HTML table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th colspan="2">span 1/2</th>
        <th colspan="3">span 2/2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
        <td>col 4</td>
        <td>col 5</td>
        <td>col 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

should be translated to

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th colspan="2">span 1/2</th>
        <th />  <!-- < empty cell added -->
        <th colspan="3">span 2/2</th>
        <th />  <!-- < empty cell added -->
    </tr>
    ..
```

(note: the output format uses a very different syntax, this is for clarity only!)

and, similarly, rowspans should be propagated to next `<tr>` lines:

```
<table><tr><td rowspan="3" /><td rowspan="2" /><td /></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
```

which should come out as

```
<table>
    <tr><td /><td /><td /></tr>
    <tr><td /><td /><td>data</td></tr>  <!-- 2 empty cells added -->
    <tr><td /><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>  <!-- 1 empty cell added -->
<table>
```

Handling `colspan` is straightforward:

```
<xsl:template name="add-empty">
    <xsl:param name="repeat" />

    <xsl:if test="$repeat &gt; 1">
        <td class="empty" />
        <xsl:call-template name="add-empty">
            <xsl:with-param name="repeat" select="$repeat - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="th|td">
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </td>
    <xsl:if test="@colspan">
        <xsl:call-template name="add-empty">
            <xsl:with-param name="repeat" select="@colspan" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will add single `th` or `td`, check each one's `colspan`, and insert as many empty cells as needed with a recursive call to the template `add-empty`. The class attribute `empty` is for debugging only.

The problem is in the `rowspan`s. For this to work properly, it needs scanning over *every* previous `tr` and keep a count of which columns need to be empty. That iteration would be something like

```
<xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
    <xsl:variable name="currentRow" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="../tr[position() &lt; $currentRow]">
        <xsl:message>testing <xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:message>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

– it does not need to be called on the first row, because for that only `colspan`s need adding. The question, then, is two-fold: how would I build the cell set list to add up to a correct set for the *current* row? And with such a list, how can I iterate over both this list (which is as long as the total number of columns in the table) *and* each row's `th|td` elements?

The latter is a problem because I can iterate over *either* the cell set using something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to string-length(cell-set)">
  <xsl:if test="substring($cell-set, ., 1) = 'E'>
    .. empty ..
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

(if `cell-set` is a string), *or* over the 'current' `tr` contents using

```
<xsl:for-each select="th|td">
  ..
```

in which case there is no direct relation to the contents of `cell-set`. With the first, I don't know which index of `td|th` to insert, with the second I don't know when to insert a blank.

Comment: As you seem to have switched to XSLT 2.0 you might want to check http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/table/table-normalization.html as an idea, it copies the existing cell instead of adding an empty one but other than that the algorithm should do, if I am not mistaken about your requirements.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I didn't as much "switch" as, somewhat late, realized I'd better specify that :) - the task seems daunting enough, even *with* 2.0 features. Will look in to the link and your answer a.s.a.p. (Ah - for example, `for-each select="1 to @colspan"` instead of my own recursive template in 1.0... neat!)

Comment: @RadLexus See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27217608/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I saw that (and upvoted) but had trouble converting it for my needs, although it was *very* close. (I also upvoted one of your additional comments )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/table/table-normalization.html which I already mentioned in a link you could use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="table_with_no_colspans">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="colspan" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="table_with_no_rowspans">
        <xsl:for-each select="$table_with_no_colspans">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="rowspan" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$table_with_no_rowspans" mode="final" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="#current" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td | th" mode="colspan">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@colspan">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @colspan"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each select="2 to @colspan">
                    <td/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- make sure it works for both table/tr and table/tbody/tr -->
    <xsl:template match="tbody|table[not(tbody)]" mode="rowspan">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="tr[1]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[2]" mode="rowspan">
                <xsl:with-param name="previousRow" select="tr[1]" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr" mode="rowspan">
        <xsl:param name="previousRow" as="element()" />

        <xsl:variable name="currentRow" select="." />

        <xsl:variable name="normalizedTDs">
            <xsl:for-each select="$previousRow/*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@rowspan &gt; 1">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@rowspan - 1" />
                            </xsl:attribute><!--
                            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name() = 'rowspan')]" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
                        --></xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$currentRow/*[1 + count(current()/preceding-sibling::*[not(@rowspan) or (@rowspan = 1)])]" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="newRow" as="element(tr)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$currentRow/@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$normalizedTDs" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy-of select="$newRow" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tr[1]" mode="rowspan">
            <xsl:with-param name="previousRow" select="$newRow" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td | th" mode="final">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@rowspan">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @rowspan" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works a treat. I still have to figure out how and where `tr`s are generated (I have to translate them to tagged text) but no worries, I'll get there. I noticed the value of `colspan` is silently discarded, which is logical – but I still need that value. Adding a `<xsl:attribute name="colspan" select="$colspan" />` after your `<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @colspan" />` fixed that. (For interested lurkers: most of the `xsl:copy` can safely be translated to `xsl:apply-templates`, with an additional `mode` to copy its contents only.)

Comment: If you want to copy the `colspan` then doing `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @colspan" />` suffices as the latter copies all attributes except the `colspan` attribute while the former would copy all attributes. As for the `tr` elements, in the mode `colspan` and the mode `final`, they are simply copied by the identity transformation template `<xsl:template match="@*|*" mode="#all">` set up for all modes. In the mode `rowspan` there is `<xsl:template match="tr" mode="rowspan">`. So you probably need a template `match="tr" mode="final"`.