# Add an element on specific location

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML and want to insert `ENTRY` on specific locations.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A4</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5<PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="20" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B4</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A10</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A11</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A12</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A12</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A13</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

XSLT version 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:template match="TBODY/ROW[position() > 1]">

    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:element name="ENTRY"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
<xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A4</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5<PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="20" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B4</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A8</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A9</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A10</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A11</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A12</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A12</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A13</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

In case `MOREROWS` is detected, leave the first row and insert `ENTRY` from the second row.

`MOREROWS` is used for spanning the cells.

[image]

Comment: When you use `namest` and `nameend` for spanning columns, do you still need to add empty `entry` nodes thereafter? I think you are misunderstanding CALS table.

Comment: As an alternative you could consider using direct DOM API and do insertBefore

Comment: Hi @Joel M. Lamsen .I already have a XSL defined for the XML and I use the customized MOREROWS for spanning. The above XML is what I have and I'm not able to get the rendering correct(data is entered in wrong column). As a result, the desired output is giving me the correct rendered table with data in the right columns.

Comment: @Ironluca Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Can position()>1 be used with `MOREROEWS`?

Comment: maybe you should convert CALS to HTML table.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen My limitation is to use XML only :(

Comment: Your input has  `<PARA>` instead of `</PARA>` at line #36.

Comment: The logic that needs to applied here is not at all clear. Please explain what you mean by "*In case `MOREROWS` is detected*". In your example, **every** `ROW` that does not have a `MOREROWS` attribute gets an extra `ENTRY`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks. But is there a way to perform the solution in the XSLT?

Comment: @ShravanVishwanathan I will answer that after you explain **exactly** what needs to be done here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have attached a sample figure in the post for clarity.

Comment: I wish you would explain the logic **in words**.  Do you mean that when MOREROWS="5" then the next 5 ROWs should get an extra ENTRY?

Comment: For Example `MOREROWS` in `<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>` is used to combine the cells in that column for the next 13 cells. The `ROWSEP` is used to separate the data in rows and `COLSEP` is used to specify in which column the data has to be entered.  It can be compared to 'Merge' concept in excel.

Comment: `MOREROWS` can be compared to Merge in MS excel.

Comment: I did something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608877/please-suggest-for-xslt-code-for-table-rowspan-and-colspan-issues/27217608#27217608

Comment: @michael.hor257k It is much complicated than my issue. not able to follow!

Comment: Your issue is no less complicated, IMHO, because MOREROWS could appear in any column. I am afraid I don't have the time to solve this now.

Comment: can something like `<xsl:template match="ENTRY[MOREROWS[position() > 1]]">` be added?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the above comment, please find the below code (NOTE: I am using depricated API for quick demonstration, replace the same with appropriate API):

```
package xml;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat;
import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class InsertChildTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("E:\\workspaces\\dev_werewolf\\GeneralTests\\XML_Questions\\ATemplate.xml");

        InputSource inputSource=new InputSource(fis);

        DOMParser parser=new DOMParser();
        parser.parse(inputSource);

        Document document=parser.getDocument();

        NodeList questionList=document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Question");

        Element someElement=document.createElement("SomeElement");
        document.getDocumentElement().insertBefore(someElement, questionList.item(1));

        OutputFormat outputFormat=new OutputFormat();
        XMLSerializer serializer=new XMLSerializer(new FileWriter("E:\\workspaces\\dev_werewolf\\GeneralTests\\XML_Questions\\ATemplate_Modified.xml"), outputFormat);

        serializer.serialize(document);

    }//main closing

}//class closing
```

The Input File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Questionnaire identifier="questionnaire_id">

    <Question slNo="1" type="closedEnded" remarks="true" singleSelect="true">
        <QuestionText>what is this?</QuestionText>
        <Options>
            <Option caption="option1" value="45-56" weightage="4"/>
            <Option caption="option2" value="85-906" weightage="10"/>
            <Option caption="option1" value="None of the above" weightage="5"/>
        </Options>
        <Answers>
            <Option caption="option1" value="45-56" weightage="4"/>
        </Answers>
    </Question>

    <Question slNo="2" type="openEnded" remarks="false">
        <QuestionText>What is that?</QuestionText>
        <Answers>
            <Text>what is what!? I do not understand</Text>
        </Answers>
    </Question>

    <Question slNo="3" type="mixed" remarks="false" singleSelect="false">
        <QuestionText>what is the other thing?</QuestionText>
        <Options>
            <Option caption="option4" value="Bad" weightage="9"/>
            <Option caption="option5" value="somewhat good" weightage="10"/>
            <Option caption="option6" value="extremely bad" weightage="10"/>
        </Options>
        <Answers>
            <Option caption="option4" value="Bad" weightage="9"/>
            <Option caption="option5" value="somewhat good" weightage="10"/>
            <Option caption="option6" value="extremely bad" weightage="10"/>
            <Text>what is what!? I do not understand</Text>
        </Answers>
    </Question>

</Questionnaire>
```

The out put file is (Notice the SomeElement, inserted before the 2nd question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Questionnaire identifier="questionnaire_id">

    <Question remarks="true" singleSelect="true" slNo="1" type="closedEnded">
        <QuestionText>what is this?</QuestionText>
        <Options>
            <Option caption="option1" value="45-56" weightage="4"/>
            <Option caption="option2" value="85-906" weightage="10"/>
            <Option caption="option1" value="None of the above" weightage="5"/>
        </Options>
        <Answers>
            <Option caption="option1" value="45-56" weightage="4"/>
        </Answers>
    </Question>

    <SomeElement/><Question remarks="false" slNo="2" type="openEnded">
        <QuestionText>What is that?</QuestionText>
        <Answers>
            <Text>what is what!? I do not understand</Text>
        </Answers>
    </Question>

    <Question remarks="false" singleSelect="false" slNo="3" type="mixed">
        <QuestionText>what is the other thing?</QuestionText>
        <Options>
            <Option caption="option4" value="Bad" weightage="9"/>
            <Option caption="option5" value="somewhat good" weightage="10"/>
            <Option caption="option6" value="extremely bad" weightage="10"/>
        </Options>
        <Answers>
            <Option caption="option4" value="Bad" weightage="9"/>
            <Option caption="option5" value="somewhat good" weightage="10"/>
            <Option caption="option6" value="extremely bad" weightage="10"/>
            <Text>what is what!? I do not understand</Text>
        </Answers>
    </Question>

</Questionnaire>
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to do this in the XSLT only ?

Comment: Certainly, in your XPath try a full XPath /TABLE/TGROUP/TBODY/ROW[position() > 1] and pass the Document object

Comment: But I believe the `MOREROWS` condition will not be met by that.