# XML to XML Table @rowspan conversion conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am having an XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <table>
        <tr>
             <td rowspan="1">0</td>
             <td rowspan="3">1</td>
             <td rowspan="1">2</td>
             <td rowspan="2">3</td>
             <td rowspan="1">4</td>
             <td rowspan="1">5</td>
             <td rowspan="2">6</td>
             <td rowspan="2">7</td>
             <td rowspan="1">8</td>
             <td rowspan="2">9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td rowspan="1">10</td>
             <td rowspan="1">11</td>
             <td rowspan="1">12</td>
             <td rowspan="1">13</td>
             <td rowspan="1">14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td rowspan="1">15</td>
             <td rowspan="1">16</td>
             <td rowspan="1">17</td>
             <td rowspan="1">18</td>
             <td rowspan="1">19</td>
             <td rowspan="1">20</td>
             <td rowspan="1">21</td>
             <td rowspan="1">22</td>
             <td rowspan="1">23</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Which should be converted to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <table>
        <tr>
             <td rowspan="1">0</td>
             <td rowspan="3">1</td>
             <td rowspan="1">2</td>
             <td rowspan="2">3</td>
             <td rowspan="1">4</td>
             <td rowspan="1">5</td>
             <td rowspan="2">6</td>
             <td rowspan="2">7</td>
             <td rowspan="1">8</td>
             <td rowspan="2">9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td rowspan="1">10</td>
             <row-span-anchor/>
             <td rowspan="1">11</td>
             <row-span-anchor/>
             <td rowspan="1">12</td>
             <td rowspan="1">13</td>
             <row-span-anchor/>
             <row-span-anchor/>
             <td rowspan="1">14</td>
             <row-span-anchor/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td rowspan="1">15</td>
             <row-span-anchor/>
             <td rowspan="1">16</td>
             <td rowspan="1">17</td>
             <td rowspan="1">18</td>
             <td rowspan="1">19</td>
             <td rowspan="1">20</td>
             <td rowspan="1">21</td>
             <td rowspan="1">22</td>
             <td rowspan="1">23</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The requirement is when there is any `@rowspan` element, that should convert as something like `<row-span-anchor/>` in the corresponding place in the converted XML.

Can this be achieved using XSLT2?

**Note:** if `td[@rowspan > 1]` then, `<row-span-anchor/>` should be placed on next row's corresponding `td` (or successive rows). For example: `/table/tr[1]/td[2]` have `@rowspan=3`, then `<row-span-anchor/>` should be placed after `/table/tr[2]/td[1]` and `/table/tr[3]/td[1]`. In first row -fourth, seventh, eighth and tenth column (`td`) have `@rowspan=2`, hence in second row (`/table/tr[2]`) `<row-span-anchor/>` is placed.

Comment: I maybe low on IQ, but looking at the source and target XML files, I am unable to find a correlation. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Although all `<td>` elements have a `rowspan` attribute, yet you have inserted `<row-span-anchor/>` elements randomly.

Comment: @Madeyedexter: Sorry that was an error. Now corrected. Please check if this is reasonable?

Comment: you add `<row-span-anchor/>`, but when do you exactly want it to be added?  Every `<td>` element has a `rowspan` attribute, so according to your question, every `<td>` element must have a corresponding `<row-span-anchor`, which is clearly not the case in your expected output.

Comment: @Madeyedexter: I have added a note at the end of the question. Is that OK?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27217608/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k: How can I place the `<row-span-anchor/>`?